# Exclude certain value in column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, where-clause, timestampdiff

I want to exclude every 0 in the column "Hoi"

[Database](https://gyazo.com/0a8ac29ff83f547ac9ae479ae1b579c1)

```
select address, min(from_unixtime(time)) "Aankomsttijd", max(from_unixtime(time)) "Eindtijd",
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,min(from_unixtime(time)),max(from_unixtime(time))) "hoi"
from sensordata1
group by address
```

I tried a where statement but it displayed "Unknown column hoi in where statement."

Comment: add  `having hoi > 0` to the end of the query

Comment: Thx this worked perfectly!! <3

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select address, Aankomsttijd, Eindtijd , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Aankomsttijd,Eindtijd) "hoi" from ()
select address, min(from_unixtime(time)) "Aankomsttijd", max(from_unixtime(time)) "Eindtijd",
from sensordata1
where 
group by address)
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Aankomsttijd,Eindtijd) >0

Comment: "hoi" is an alias not a column

Comment: It gives a error back. Saying the group function is not used correctly

Comment: Neither aliases nor aggregate functions are available in the `where` clause. Either version should work if you move to a `having` clause.

Comment: Your code didnt work but the code from @juergen d worked perfectly so I got the answer anyway thx for helping! appreciate the work tho!